# Proof that a function with continuous partial derivatives has directional derivatives in all directions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

I tried to prove it, but I would appreciate if someone could check my answer. I am just starting to learn real analysis on my own Thank you for helping. :)

**Theorem**

Let $f\colon \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ have continuous first partial derivatives at each point.

Then $f$ has directional derivatives in all directions at each point.

**Proof**

Let $\vec p$ be any non-zero vector in $\Bbb R^2$.

Choose $r>0$.

By the mean value proposition, we see that if $t$ is any number such that $|t|\lVert \vec p \rVert < r$, then there are $n$ points $z_1,\ldots,z_n\in\Bbb R^2$ such that
$$f(x+t\vec p)-f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n t p_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(z_i)$$
and $\lVert z_i - x \rVert < |t|\lVert p \rVert$ for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Then we can write
$$\frac{f(x+t\vec p)-f(x)} t =\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(z_i)$$

Since $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}$ is continuous for each $i$,

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+t\vec p)-f(x)} t = \lim_{t\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(z_i)$$ exists, so $f$ has a derivative in the $\vec p$ direction at $x$.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: What is $p$? You haven't defined it.

Comment: $p$ is nonzero point in $\Bbb R^2$ @dfeuer  Is the proof true?

Comment: I think you need to expand on your invocation of the mean value proposition.

Comment: Wow rewrote this with latex :) thank you:) but can you check this proof? @Dfeuer

Comment: Sorry I am trying to improve myself. I am new learner and I am studying real analysis by my self on summer holiday for next semester.@Dfeuer

Comment: Don't apologize. Just explain that part.

Comment: Okay! Is this proof true and enough? @dfeuer

Comment: It's not sufficient in my view. This formulation of the mean value theorem looks fishy to me. I think you need more sums, to sum over the components of $f$.

Comment: Then can you show me in detail please help me:) @Dfeuer

Comment: Can you correct? @dfeuer

Comment: Did you intend to write $\Bbb R^n$ everywhere you wrote $\Bbb R^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you also forgot to normalize your vector $\,\vec p\,$ . Taking it from where you were, and assuming we already have $\,||\vec p||=1\,$ , we have by definition with $\,\bf x:=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\;$

$$D_{\vec p}f(\bf x):=\text{The directional derivative of $\,f\,$ at point $\,\bf x\,$ in the direction of $\,\vec p$}:=$$

$$:= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+t\vec p)-f(x)}t\stackrel{\text{Chain Rule}}=\sum_{k=1}^n \vec p\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(a_1,...,a_n)=\nabla f(\bf{x})\cdot\bf \vec p$$

So if the function is differentiable at any point (say, when the partial derivatives exist *and* are continuous at any point), its directional derivative in **any** direction exists and it's pretty easy to calculate by means of the gradient of $\,f\,$ .

**Added:** We want the directional derivative of $\;f\;,\;f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\;$ at the point $\,x:=(x_1,...,x_n)\,$ and in the direction $\,p:=(p_1,...,p_n)\,$ (no little arrows, no nothing) .

We also assume $\,||p||:=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n p_i^2}=1\;$ (note then that you will **have** to normalize the vector in which direction you want the derivative in case it is not normalized!).

Now we define a new function

$$g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n\;,\;\;g(t):=x+tp=\left(x_1+tp_1\,,\,x_2+tp_2\,,\ldots,x_n+tp_n\right):=(g_1(t),...,g_n(t))$$

Note that $\;\forall\,t\;,\;\,g'(t)=p\implies g'(0)=p\,$ , and we also denote the derivative of some function $\,k\,$ by $\,Dk\,$ and by $\,D_uk\,$ the directional derivative of $\,k\,$ in the direction of $\,u\,$, for simplicity.

Thus, *by definition* we get that

$$D_pf(x):=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+tp)-f(x)}t=\left.\frac d{dt}(f(x+tp))\right|_{t=0}=\left.D(f\circ g)(t)\right|_{t=0}\stackrel{\text{chain rule}}=$$

$$=Df(g(0))\cdot Dg(0)=\left(f'_{x_1}(g(0))\,,\,f'_{x_2}(g(0))\,,\ldots,f'_{x_n}(g(0))\right)\cdot(g'_1(0)\,,\,\ldots,g'_n(0))=$$

$$\left(f'_{x_1}(g(0))\,,\,f'_{x_2}(g(0))\,,\ldots,f'_{x_n}(g(0))\right)\cdot(p_1,...,p_n)=\nabla f(x)\cdot p$$

which is what we wrote above...:)

**IMPORTANT:** You can use the gradient as above to calculate the directional derivative **only** if you're sure the partial derivatives exist in some neighborhood of $\,x\,$  *and* are continuous there.

Comment: That's begining of my proof while I am defining $p$, I Will write all you said, and then I will continue to do other parts. Other parts are true. Is it right?

Comment: I dont understand, sorry:( well, what happens $z_i$?

Comment: Please show me step by step? Thank you:)

Comment: I shall write a more detailed answer in a little while, @B11b . Wait some minutes for it.

Comment: Okay No problem! I have lots of time. I am waiting.. :)

Comment: @B11b, it is ready. Enjoy!

Comment: I am shocked! I would like to upvote more and more:))) got it well:) I am studying your answer step by step right now! thank you so much. You are the best! :)) @DonAntonio

Comment: Oh, I am so not the best...! Anyway, a pleasure if you *enjoy* and also learn something. It's happened to me many times even when teaching.

Comment: Do you not like marking vectors with \vec? That's a matter of personal taste, right?

Comment: More importantly, if $\Vert p\Vert≠1$, isn't the directional derivative defined anyway, scaling linearly?

Comment: Indeed so,@dfeuer .I, just like many other mathematicians I've known (no names!) am pretty writing-lazy, so if I can use short writings I will. It though can be important touse little vectors or other notation when one first begins studying multivariable\vector calculus, in order to make a sharp distinction with one variable calculus. But this need usually disappears after some little while.

Comment: As far as I know @dfeuer, the direction must be normalized. The directional derivative is defined precisely as that: something in one particular direction. It is so that the director cosines are also commonly used to define the dir. derivative, and then there is no specific vector at all.